# How do I get the actual used memory including RAM disks?

Tags: memory-usage

`free -m` does not seems to include memory used by RAM disks (tmpfs filesystems). Maybe because it's something in the kernel space?

How do I get the *real memory usage* (or it's opposite, *free memory*) including the allocated space of filesystems that reside in RAM like `tmpfs`?

I currently check for the memory usage by running `df -h` and adding the "In use" numbers to the `-/+ buffers/cache` number. Is there a command available that gives me the *real* memory usage?

Comment: Could you share some more info, such as the output of `free -m; cat /proc/meminfo; swapon -s; mount` (while you have that tmpfs you mention)

Comment: Oh, and `df -h` -- Darn, I just noticed that this question is old, sorry.

Comment: @medigeek You can reproduce it with `free -m;cat /proc/meminfo>1; dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/big bs=1M count=400; free -m;cat /proc/meminfo>2;diff -u 1 2` (assuming that `/tmp` is mounted as tmpfs and has at least 400MiB memory available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can install htop via the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

then run htop in the terminal

*disclaimer* I guess this does not work on Lucid correctly

[image]

Comment: This memory information is the same as `free -m`. I prefer a solution that gives me immediately details, without refreshing like `free`. The calculation could be done with `awk`, but there should be a single command available, shouldn't it?

Comment: htop gives you non-static ram usage... in others words, it shows you exactly what kind of ram you are using at any given time, as long as you have it running.

Comment: @TheX: I think I've not been clear then, this number does not include memory usage by ram disks. Try it yourself, create a 200MB file using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/bigfile bs=1M count=200`. You'll notice that the memory usage reported by `htop` and `free` does not change.

Comment: mine changed... I guess my next question is what exactly do you mean by disk ram?

Comment: @TheX: weird, it seems to work on Natty, but not on Lucid. I can't find anything in the changelogs ([natty](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/procps/procps_3.2.8-10ubuntu3/changelog) and [lucid](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/procps/procps_3.2.8-1ubuntu4/changelog)). Must be a kernel change?

Comment: yeah that is strange...

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it works, but can you add details on the `lucid` exception? You can also add formatting to your `sudo apt-get htop` command by prefixing it with four spaces.

Comment: Okay, I don't know what's going on. `htop` shows my memory usage as 1G while I've over 2.5G in `/tmp` mounted as tmpfs (mostly used by a Komodo Edit build from source). Any ideas? I'm using Kubuntu Natty, freshly installed using an alternate CD. `free -m` (without removing buffers/cache) shows a more correct number.

Answer (score 2):

According to [a redhat guide](https://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-memory.html):

> When you interpret the values reported by memory.stat, note how the
>   various statistics inter-relate:
>
> active_anon + inactive_anon = anonymous memory + file cache for tmpfs + swap cache
>
> Therefore, active_anon + inactive_anon ≠ rss, because rss does not include tmpfs.
>
> active_file + inactive_file = cache - size of tmpfs

According to that, there must be some co-relation to the command output of `cat /proc/meminfo`

```
Active:           346284 kB
Inactive:         497060 kB
Active(anon):     146212 kB
Inactive(anon):   197168 kB
Active(file):     200072 kB
Inactive(file):   299892 kB
```